# update status from active to inactive using codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, sql-update, status

Hi when i want to update my status using a button from inactive to active through ajax method so i have written some code i dont know wether it is right or wrong but status is not updating

Comment: Check if your ajax is firing and sending the new status to model

Comment: you are not passing data to update. $this->db->update('courses', $data); // gives you undefined variable $data .   https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sample code, This should work

Controller:

```
public function update_status(){

    $status = $this->input->post('status');
    $course_id = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->CoursesModel->update_course_status($course_id,$status);
}
```

Model:

```
public function update_course_status($course_id,$status){
  $data['status'] = $status;
  $this->db->where('course_id', $course_id);
  $this->db->update('courses',$data);
}
```

Script:

```
$(document).on('click','.status_checks',function()
 { 

var status = ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) ? '1' : '0'; 
var msg = (status=='0')? 'Deactivate' : 'Activate'; 
if(confirm("Are you sure to "+ msg))
{ 
    var current_element = $(this); 
    var id = $(current_element).attr('data');
    url = "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/Dashboard/update_status'?>"; 
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url: url, 
          data: {"id":id,"status":status}, 
          success: function(data) { 
          // if you want reload the page
          location.reload();
          //if you want without reload
          if(status == '1'){
            current_element.removeClass('btn-success');
            current_element.addClass('btn-danger');
            current_element.html('Deactivate');
          }else{
            current_element.removeClass('btn-danger');
            current_element.addClass('btn-success');
            current_element.html('Activate');
          }
    } });
 }  
 });
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="status_checks btn <?php echo ($element->status == 1) ? "btn-danger" : "btn-success"; ?> "><?php echo ($element->status == 1) ? "Deactivate" : "Activate"; ?></button>
```

Comment: please edit your answer & add code of view button.

Comment: @KUMAR Answer updated.

Comment: its done but it reloads the page.

Comment: @KUMAR Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should put some info in $data like so

```
$data['status'] = $status;
$this->db->where('course_id', $course_id);
$this->db->update('courses', $data);
```

Hope it solves the problem !